# taking flexible arguments in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, argument-passing

I'm trying to take flexible arguments in javascript to manipulate color with the eyecon colorpicker ([www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/))

But when I try to change color the page hangs, is it getting stuck in the arguments.length loop?

the html is:

```
<div class="colorSelector" id="colorSelector3"><div style="background-color: #0000ff"></div></div>
```

and the jquery/javascript is:

```
$('#colorSelector3').click(function(){
colorPickDynamic('#colorSelector3','h1','color');
});


function colorPickDynamic(cp){

var i;
var j;

for (x=0, i = 1, j = 2; j < arguments.length; i+2, j+2, x++) {

var tag = [];
var colorProperty = [];
tag[x]=arguments[i];
colorProperty[x]=arguments[j];
}

$(cp).ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {

                            $(tag[0]).css(colorProperty[0], '#' + hex);

        $(cp + ' div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
});
}
```

any help would be amazing! thanks

Comment: can you define more explicitly what you want the method signature of `colorPickDynamic` to be. In other words, what should each argument, or list of arguments represent?

Comment: arguments[0], arguments[1]...
arguments.length is also there

Comment: note that "arguments" is not a real array, just a work-around if i may

Answer (score 6):

You have an infinite loop, you are never incremementing `j`.

`j+2` should be `j+=2`, `i+2` should be `i+=2`

Comment: how silly of me, switching from c to javascript ive become much less attentive! ill try this when i get back to the computer, thanks!

Comment: hmm it is still stuck in this loop with j+=2 and i+=2? is the logic wrong?